# update column values from another table with different column name but same column value in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sql-update

update column values from another table with different column name but same column value

I have two tables as mentioned below :

Table1

```
ID | Name
1  | A
2  | A
3  | A
4  | A
```

Table2

```
IDX | Name
1   | XYZ
2   | PQR
3   | PPS

update Table1
set Name = (Select Name from Table2 where Table1.ID = Table2.IDX)
```

I'm getting below result after executing above query.

```
ID | Name
1  | XYZ
2  | PQR
3  | PPS
4  | NULL
```

But I need result as mentioned below:

```
ID | Name
1  | XYZ
2  | PQR
3  | PPS
4  | A
```

Can somebody help with this ? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `isnull` however a join is better as it only touches rows that can be updated.

Comment: Thank you below works for me `code` update Table1 
     set Name = (select Table2.name from Table2 where Table2.IDX = Table1.ID)
 where exists (select * from Table2 where Table1.ID = Table2.IDX);`code`

Answer (score 2):

Using an update join we can try:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET Name = t2.Name
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.IDX = t1.ID;
```

Only records from `Table1` which match to something in `Table2` will be updated.  This avoids the problem of making a null assignment from which your current approach suffers.  You could make the following slight change to your current update to avoid the problem:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET Name = (SELECT COALESCE(t2.Name, Table1.Name) FROM Table2 t2
            WHERE Table1.ID = t2.IDX);
```

Comment: getting syntax error : (UPDATE Table1 t1
SET Name = (SELECT COALESCE(t2.Name, t1.Name) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.IDX);